# Multiple table query and form

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to write a query in MS Access and I am having some trouble with the logic/format. One part of the form is a check box field that allows users to select different properties. ( ISO certifications NADCAP etc) I need to write the query in such a way that if it is selected only records where it is true are returned but if it is not selected it is ignored.

Comment: What have you tried for creating a query so far and how are you calling your query?  [This is probably what you are looking for](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/using-parameters-with-queries-and-reports-HA001117077.aspx)

Comment: I'm going to call the query with a submit button. But my problem is more basic than that. If company A has the ISO 9000 and 9001 and the 9000 button is selected but the 9001 is not how do I get it to still return company A. Because right now it will read " ISO 9000 = true and ISO 9001 = false".

Comment: It sound like you might need a TRI-value selection --  Include 9000, Unknown9000, Exclude9000   ... ... etc for 9001